# PHP array_values sorted by given indexes

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object

Data is in this format, a list on an unarranged object array.

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => {#688 ▼
    +"title": "My Item 1"
    +"categories": "3,4,5,6"
    +"sku": "1"
    +"user_id": "5"
  }
  1 => {#663 ▼
    +"title": "My Item 1"
    +"sku": "2"
    +"categories": "3,4,5,6"
    +"user_id": "6"
  }
  2 => {#686 ▼
    +"title": "My Item 1"
    +"user_id": "7"
    +"categories": "3,4,5,6"
    +"sku": "3"
  }
  3 => & {#290 ▼
    +"title": "My Item 1"
    +"categories": "3,4,5,6"
    +"sku": "4"
    +"user_id": "8"
  }
]
```

but I want the values in an arranged array format like `title, SKU, categories, user_id` `("My Item 1", "2,3,5,6", "1", "5")`

Right now I'm using array_values, but data comes in an unsorted way such as index 1 SKU is before the categories, how can I get it? is there some native PHP or Laravel method that we can use?

Edit: The above one is just an example array, the real data has 50+ columns, so I can't define them statically in a loop.

Thanks

Comment: You may use array sort by key

Comment: @A.ANoman ksort will make it categories, sku, title, user_id,  I want it to be title, SKU, categories, user_id  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to sort the keys, you could use `ksort()`, if you want them in specific order you could restructure the array like:

```
$arr = [...your array];
$newArr = [];

foreach ($arr as $item) {
    $newItem = [
        'title' => $item['title'],
        'SKU' => $item['SKU'],
        'categories' => $item['categories'],
        'user_id' => $item['user_id']
    ];

    array_push($newArr, $newItem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `array_push` if you want to custom array index like below

```
$expectedArray = array();

foreach ($your_array as $data){

    array_push($expectedArray ,array(

        'title'        => $data['title'],
        'SKU'          => $data['SKU'],
        'categories'   => $data['categories'],
        'user_id'      => $data['user_id']

    ));
}
```

Comment: Actually, I have a very large array with many more columns (the above one is just an example), but I do have a $columns keys array, I just want my array data to be arranged

Comment: @MZH, Ok fine. Please check your keys `alphabetical orders. If keys are `alphabetical then no need `array_push` but if you need `custom` key then you have no alternative